# Passing Dictionary into table view using swift 4

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

```
I have Created two Dictionary of question and answer , and I have created two label in my table view for displaying question and their options serial wise , but after displaying the result into the table view it is shown as the given screenshot , help me to show these data in standard for of question and answer with options

*I have created Dictionary of two* 

`[Int:String]`and [Int:Array<String>] 
 , *and now I want access it in my Table view serially with dictionary1 in question label and dictionary2 in answer label;* 

Code --

        var dictionary1:[Int:String] = 
       [0:"Whether you have experienced Pricking-pain, Desquamation,itching or dry skin sensation during seasonal alternate.",
        1:"Whether your skin apt to flush( Redness) in hot humid environment ",
        2:"Whether your skin has multiple disernible dilated capillaries.",
        3:"whether you have once been diagnosed atopic dermatitis or seborrheic dermatitis."]
```

*Dictionary2 for creating options to the questions*

```
 var dictionary2 : [Int:Array<String>] = 
 [0:["Never","Seldom","Usually","Always"],
 1:["Never","Seldom","Usually","Always"],
 2:["Never","Seldom","Usually","Always"],
 3:["Yes", "No"]]


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dictionary1.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    cell.questionLabel.text = dictionary1[indexPath.row]
        cell.questionLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        let arr = dictionary2[indexPath.row]

        var strr = String()
        for str in arr! {
            strr = strr + str
        }
        cell.optionsLabel.text = strr
        cell.optionsLabel.textColor = UIColor.black

        return cell
    }

    }
```

**// HERE IS THE SCREENSHOT OF MY TABLE VIEW , IT IS NOT SHOWING THE DATA IN MULTILINE AND THE OPTIONS AND THE QUESTION ARE OVERLAPPING**

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

1. List item

   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Erpvq.png

Comment: key must be string, You cannot defined as `Int`

Comment: @ShabbirAhmad You're wrong here. It can be `AnyHashable` including an `Int`.

Comment: At which line this error is? And what is `NSObject.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: [indexPath.row])` ?

Comment: `cell.optionsLabel.text = dictionary1[indexPath.row]` should work.

Comment: `dictionary1` is defined `[Int:String]` the key is an `Int` and `value` is a `String` so it will work for sure.

Comment: @Sudhir `cell.optionsLabel.text = dictionary1[indexPath.row]` this code definitely works

Comment: cell.optionsLabel.text = dictionary1[indexPath.row] is working but nothing is showing in my table view

Comment: @Sudhir You have accepted the answer already. That means your problem has been solved.

Comment: Yes It is solved now !!! Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace below delegate with yours:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
    // TO Display Single Dictionary Data
    cell.textLabel?.text = dictionary1[indexPath.row]


    // To display Array of string stored in dictionary
    cell.textLabel?.text = dictionary2[indexPath.row]?.joined(separator: "\n")

    return cell
}
```

**For 2nd Requirement**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dictionary1.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell

    // FOR FIRST DICTIONARY
    cell.lblFirst?.text = dictionary1[indexPath.row]

    // FOR SECOND DICTIONARY
    cell.lblSecond?.text = dictionary2[indexPath.row]?.joined(separator: "\n")

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Hello downVoter, can you please guide me what the issue in this code?

Comment: @Sudhir, I tried this code and it's working fine, did you check by changing `textColor`?

Comment: How can i display Array of string stored in dictionary to another label in my table view ?

Comment: var dictionary2:[Int:Array<String>] = [0:["Never","Seldom","Usually","Always"],1:["Never","Seldom","Usually","Always"],2:["Never","Seldom","Usually","Always"],3:["Yes", "No"]] , i have this dictionary and the same is showing error like previous one

Comment: @Sudhir, see my updated answer to **display Array of string stored in dictionary**

Comment: @Kuldeep You can use function for this `array.joined()` it will return `String` by concatenating all elements.

Comment: And `var strr = String()` should be replace by `var strr = ""` in your existing code.

Comment: @TheTiger thanks for your suggestion, I will update this soon.

Comment: @Kuldeep , why cant i use ,dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: [indexPath.row])  method , because i have stored my data in the form of dictionary and i want to access it through key values which is in my case is "Int" , can you help me in this ?

Comment: @Sudhir, what data you have and how you access them, update your question with the issue.

Answer (score -1):

**Note: I wanted to make it a comment, but I also wanted to share this image so I answered, but it's a hint, not the complete answer.**

1. The function you are using takes an array of String as input. you can see the below screen for any function by pressing the option key and clicking the function body.

[image]

2. You need to pass the key as a string. then your dictionary must have a key type as String. Once you make the key a string.

**Possible solutions are:**

1. if you are keeping key as Int, then use: `dictionary1[indexPath.row]`

   if you make your key as a string then use: `dictionary1["\(indexPath.row)"]`
2. (Just for this case) If you want to show them in a sequence only like 0th element 1st element.. then why not use an Array instead of Dictionary.

   `arry = ["1st description","2nd description"]`

and then use

```
cell.label.text = arry[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: `as Any` is wrong here `cell.optionsLabel.text` accepts `String`.

Comment: @TheTiger I edited that before seeing your comment. It's just a hint for him not the answer. Please see the updated answer

Comment: I change it to string as well , still it is showing the same error , just tell me how can i display dictionary data elements into the table view